# Wald interval for ratio of multinomial parameters

Tags: confidence-interval, multinomial-distribution, wald-test

In a trinomial distribution with parameters $p_1, p_2$ I am interested in the parameter $\theta=\frac{p_1}{p_2}$. I would like to find the Wald confidence interval for this parameter, but I think that the correlation between the two events $X_1, X_2$ may create some troubles. Thereby, the confidence interval $$\frac{p_1}{p_2}\exp\left[\pm z_{\frac{\alpha}{2}}\sqrt{\frac{1-p_1}{n_1p_1}+\frac{1-p_2}{n_2p_2}}\right]$$ wouldn't be correct, since it takes the two values $p_1$ and $p_2$ as independent, as far as I understand. This said, is there any way to compute a Wald Interval for the ratio of multinomial parameters that takes into account their dependent structure?

Comment: Is $n$ large enough to apply Maximum Likelihood theory?

Answer (score 1):

**By using $\theta$ directly as a parameter there will be no difficulty.**

Let the observed counts associated with probabilities $(p_1,p_2,p_3)$ in a sample of size $n$ be $(n_1,n_2,n - n_1 - n_2).$  Because the likelihood in terms of the parameters $p=p_2$ and $\theta = p_1/p_2$ is

$$L(p,\theta;n_1,n_2,n_3)\ \propto\ (\theta p)^{n_1} (p)^{n_2} (1 - \theta p - p)^{n - n_1 - n_2},$$

the log likelihood is readily computed and a unique minimum is found at

$$(\hat\theta, \hat p) = \left(\frac{n_1}{n_2}, \frac{n_2}{n}\right)$$

provided $n_2 \gt 0.$  Let's assume from now on that $p_2 n$ is large enough for the chance that $n_2=0$ to be small enough to neglect.  (A lower threshold around $5$ ought to suffice, because the Poisson approximation to the distribution of $n_2$ suggests this chance drops below 1%.)

The variance-covariance matrix of this Maximum Likelihood estimate is the inverse of the Hessian of the log likelihood, given by

$$\hat\Sigma = \pmatrix{\frac{n_1(n_1+n_2)}{n_2^3} & -\frac{n_1}{n n_2}\\-\frac{n_1}{n n_2} & \frac{n_2 (n - n_2)}{n^3}}.$$

The square root of the upper left term is the estimated standard error of $\hat \theta,$

$$\widehat{\operatorname{se}}(\hat\theta) = \sqrt{\frac{n_1(n_1+n_2)}{n_2^3}}.$$

The Wald confidence interval of size $\alpha,$ then, is spanned by the values of $\hat\theta \mp Z_{\alpha/2} \widehat{\operatorname{se}}(\hat\theta)$ where $Z_{\alpha/2}$ is the $\alpha/2$ percentile of the standard Normal distribution.

---

Simulations with $p=1/5$ and $\theta\in\{1/2, 1, 2, 3\}$ for $n \in \{20, 50, 100, 200\}$ suggest the Wald interval for $\alpha = 0.05$ (the standard 95% confidence) tends to have low coverage but comes close to 95% coverage provided $n \ge 100.$  Here is a summary of the fraction of 10,000 independent experiments where the Wald interval included the true value of $\theta:$

```
     theta
n      0.5    1    2    3
  20  0.85 0.90 0.90 0.92
  50  0.91 0.92 0.93 0.93
  100 0.92 0.93 0.94 0.94
  200 0.94 0.95 0.95 0.95
```

Notice that with $p=1/5$ and $\theta = 0.5,$ $np_1 = n\theta p = n/10.$  Perhaps a reasonable rule of thumb might be to trust this confidence interval provided both $np$ and $np\theta$ exceed $10$ or so.

For smaller values of $\alpha$ you need even larger sample sizes to attain the desired coverage.  Here is a summary of the simulations for $\alpha = 0.01:$

```
     theta
n       0.5     1     2     3
  20  0.870 0.921 0.947 0.945
  50  0.934 0.957 0.964 0.961
  100 0.962 0.974 0.977 0.975
  200 0.974 0.980 0.982 0.980
  500 0.985 0.988 0.987 0.988
```

The values get up to 99% only around $n=500;$ at $n=100$ the coverage is only about 97.5%.